# Adding number 1 to a variable everytime the command executes

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a code that would extend a variable in a batch file.
I have this code:

```
@echo OFF
color A
echo press Enter
pause >nul
:again
cls
set /a sum1=+1
echo press Enter(pressed %NUM% times)
cls
goto again
```

I want to extend the variable by 1, everytime the commands executes. So the output should look like this(An example):

> press Enter(pressed 3 times)

Any ideas?
Excuse my english..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct syntax is:

```
set /a sum1+=1
```

Comment: I edited the command to remove the space between the variable name and the += operator. Although it does work with the space, it might lead to confusion when people use SET without the /A option. SET /A does not support spaces within variable names, so `set /a var +=1` and `set /a var+=1` are equivalent. But the normal SET command (withoug `/A`) *does* support spaces in variable names, so `set var=val` and `set var =val` are not equivalent. I have seen many cases where people get in trouble with spaces in names. Better to be consistent with examples.

Comment: I had the space for better readabiltiy, but consistence is an argument I can happily accept.